# Sed remove tags from html file

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash

I need to remove all tags from a html with a bash script using the sed command.
I tried with this

```
sed -r 's/[\<][\/]?[a-zA-Z0-9\=\"\-\#\.\& ]+[\/]?[\>]//g' $1
```

and whith this

```
sed -r 's/[\<][\/]?[.]*[\/]?[\\]?[\>]//g' $1
```

but I still miss something, any suggestions??

Comment: Here's my favorite answer concerning HTML and Regex ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I perfectly know it, but this is a homework :-(

Comment: My school time was long ago, but I think homework isn't necessarily to show a perfect answer. It's also to show some effort at all and to have the courage to say, that's all I've come up with. :-)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can either use one of the many [HTML to text converters](https://www.google.de/search?q=html+to+text), use Perl regex if possible `<.+?>` or if it must be `sed` use `<[^>]*>`

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.html
```

If there's no room for errors, use an HTML parser instead.
E.g. when an element is spread over two lines

```
<div
>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

this regular expression will not work.

---

This regular expression consists of three parts `<`, `[^>]*`, `>`

- search for opening `<`
- followed by zero or more characters `*`, which are not the closing `>`
  `[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), when it starts with `^` look for characters *not* in the class
- and finally look for closing `>`

The simpler regular expression `<.*>` will not work, because it searches for the longest possible match, i.e. the last closing `>` in an input line. E.g., when you have more than one tag in an input line

```
<name>Olaf</name> answers questions.
```

will result in

> answers questions.

instead of

> Olaf answers questions.

See also [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), especially section [Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) and following, for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Works like a charm.. I suck at sed though, so could you please explain the <[^>]*> bit?

Comment: The `[^>]` is a character class which matches any character except `>` and the `*` says to repeat the match zero or more times. Otherwise, `<.*>` would match from the first `<` on the line to the last `>`, often spanning multiple tags.

Comment: Perfect, I needed to use `grep -Ev "<.*>"` to filter out HTML tags *and* the content in them. Thank you.

Comment: Note: This answer doesn't consider `script` tags content.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP asked for `sed` specifically but this page shows as a top result in Google even for non-sed searchers.

#### Perl one liner

```
cat - | perl -pe 's{\n}{ }g' | perl -pe 's{>}{>\n}g' | perl -pe 's{<}{\n<}g' | grep -v '<' | grep -v '^\s*$'
```

Feel free to edit this (I've marked it as community wiki), it's not perfect.

#### Explanation

Too much for me to type for now, but [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat%20-%20%7C%20perl%20-pe%20%27s%7B%5Cn%7D%7B%20%7Dg%27%20%7C%20perl%20-pe%20%27s%7B%3E%7D%7B%3E%5Cn%7Dg%27%20%7C%20perl%20-pe%20%27s%7B%3C%7D%7B%5Cn%3C%7Dg%27%20%7C%20grep%20-v%20%27%3C%27%20%7C%20grep%20-v%20%27%5E%5Cs*%24%27) is a start.

#### Other notes

I'm surprised there isn't a mature tool out there that does this, just lots of messy npm command line tools. I'm not a fan of the amount of junk npm leaves behind. A golang precompiled single binary or something via `brew install` would be the ultimate dream

Answer (score 0):

I've often used `lynx -dump -nolist <URL>` for the OP's purpose.  However, you still get formatting, so you might want to additionally strip leading blanks on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Far away from perfect, but for me it was sufficient:

```
curl -Ls https://stackoverflow.com | # load html content
tr -d '\r' |                         # remove carriage return
tr '\n' '\r' |                       # replace line breaks against carriage return to allow sed to replace across multiple lines
sed -E "s/\/(script|style)>/\n/g" |  # replace closing script/css tags against new line
sed -E "s/<(script|style).*//g" |    # replace whole script/css blocks ungreedy
sed -E 's/(="[^"]*)>/\1/g' |         # replace closing bracket inside of double quotes
sed -E "s/(='[^']*)>/\1/g" |         # replace closing bracket inside of single quotes
sed "s/<[^>]*>/ /g" |                # replace all other html tags against white space
tr '\r' '\n' |                       # replace carriage return against new line
tr '\t' ' ' |                        # replace tabulator against white space
tr -s ' ' |                          # reduce consecutive white space
sed "s/^ //g" |                      # remove white space from the beginning of each line
grep -v "^$"                         # remove empty lines
```

Returns:

```
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers 
Stack Overflow 
About 
Products
For Teams 
Stack Overflow 
Public questions &amp; answers 
Stack Overflow for Teams 
Where developers &amp; technologists share private knowledge with coworkers 
Talent 
Build your employer brand
Advertising 
Reach developers &amp; technologists worldwide 
Labs 
The future of collective knowledge sharing 
About the company 
Loading&#x2026; 
current community 
Stack Overflow
help 
chat 
...
API
Data
Blog 
Facebook 
Twitter 
LinkedIn 
Instagram 
Site design / logo &#169; 2024 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under CC BY-SA . rev&nbsp;2024.3.22.6753
```