# Remove empty HTML tags from a file using sed

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash, sed

I have looked a lot to find the solution but could not find one. I know how to remove all tags using `sed` but I need to remove only those HTML tags that are empty or have just tabs or spaces in them and also remove tags explicitly. For example:

```
<p></p>  or <p>    </p>
```

I used the following command to remove all the HTML tags, it works properly but I don't want to remove all tags.

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' myfile.html
```

same command is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file). Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below sed command to remove only the empty tags.

```
sed 's/<[^\/][^<>]*> *<\/[^<>]*>//g' file
```

Through Perl,

```
perl -pe 's/<([^<>]*)>\s*<\/\1>//g' file
```

Comment: Thanks! one more problem i that the tag doesnt always close like  `</>`, some tags are written like this `<img  src="someimage" />` . will this command still hold for these tags?

Comment: then use this `sed -r 's/<[^\/][^<>]*> *<\/?[^<>]*\/?>//g' file`

Comment: To delete empty tags with any attributes.Tags may have any amount of whitespace/new lines in body. Does not delete tags without body(<tag/>).
```perl -0 -i -p -e "s/(<[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z]*)[^>]*>)([[:space:]]*)(<\/\2>)([[:space:]]*)//g" "$path"```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)>[ \s\t]*<\/\1>//g' file
```

Comment: this will not work after you changed your requirement! :-) Since @Avinash provided the answer, i left it there :-)