# Remove <s> and </s> from all lines in file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm processing a fairly large file that I will use to create word2vec embeddings. The file contains one sentence on each line, all lines starting with a  <s>start tag and</s>  end tag. Now what I wish to do is to use sed to remove the start and end tags, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried

```
sed myfile 's/<s> //g' > resultfile
sed resultfile 's/ </s>//g' > finalfile
```

but this yields the "extra characters after command" error.

If someone could give me the right pattern I'd be very happy. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
sed 's#</\?s>##g' file
```

- this will remove `<s>` and `</s>` in one shot
- `#` is separator for sed's `s` command, since your pattern has already slash.
- the `</\?s>` is regex, it matches `<s> and </s>`

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong arguments order.

Try to use:

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' myfile.txt
```

To remove **any** html tag

Reference: [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file)

Comment: this does different thing!

Comment: that is why I mentioned... it removes ANY html tag

Comment: but are you answering OP's question?

Comment: you are right, it is not exact answer, just a quick help to align @Henrik with resolution of the issue