# How to remove an html node type?

Tags: xidel

xidel can be used to extract nodes. But I want to remove a html node type, e.g., all the `<script>` nodes. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59705407 ?

Comment: I got this error `err:XPST0017: unknown function: x:replace-nodes #2`. I have Xidel 0.9.8. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I do. Please use a more [up-to-date version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/).

Comment: Could you please put the updated version in homebrew? I use xidel in homebrew. I don't see how to install it directly on MacOS.

Comment: There are nightly builds for mac: https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master

Comment: @Reino `x:replace-nodes(//script,())` does not work if <script> does not exist in the input. In that case, all the content in <html> will be deleted. How to make the code robust so that when <script> does not exist, nothing will be done to the input?

Comment: You could use `x:replace-nodes(/,//script,())`, or `x:replace-nodes(.,//script,())`. This 3rd parameter (or 1st, depending on how you look at it) was discussed [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/videlibri/mailman/videlibri-xidel/thread/051ee1cc-55a1-e26f-2b7c-5b424c766543%40xs4all.nl/#msg37214741) and implemented. It appears [the documentation](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-replace-nodes) still needs an update for this @BeniBela.

Comment: Both commands seem to add extra newlines to the output (in my test case, it adds newlines to <body>). I'd expect that when <script> does not exist, the output should be the same as the input.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the right place for discussions like these. I suggest you visit either the [mailing-list](https://sourceforge.net/p/videlibri/mailman/), or the [forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/xidel/discussion/).