# Bash: remove html tag from page

Tags: html, bash, sed

I have some html code

```
<div><img src="..." /></div>
```

and I would like to remove the img tag from it to get:

```
<div></div>
```

I wrote a bash script with the same commands I did in emacs:

```
cat "$1"|sed 's/</\n</g'|sed 's/>/>\n/g'|sed 's/^<img.+//g' > "$2"
```

but It didn't work. It seems that sed doesn't work in line breaks. Any suggestions?

I also tried:

```
sed 's/<img.+>//g'
```

but this removes too much code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file)

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `sed 's/<img[^>]*>//g'` seems to fit my needs.

Comment: That will match some of the possible strings you want to match and will match some strings you don't want to match so YMMV. It might be OK depending on your possible input.