# How can I remove html tags, scripts, empty lines in a HTML with sed?

Tags: html, linux, bash, sed

I tried it some ways, but i can't make it.

```
sed -e "s/<!---* *<\(.*\)> *-->/<\1>/" test.html
```

I found that here, but I don't know how to continue  with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file)

Comment: Let perl be with you -  `perl -0777 -pe 's/<.*?>//sg' test.html

Comment: If you want to remove empty lines then `perl -0777 -pe 's/<.*?>//sg;s/\s+\n+/\n/g' test.html`

Comment: I have to use only sed :/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following script to **remove html /  tags** and ***output what's left***.

Input file: (test.txt)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
      }
    </script>

    <title>Sample page</title>

    <style>
      html { color: #837456; }
      body { background: white; }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Hello here!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

The command was

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/$/©/' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/<script.*<\/script>//g' | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/©/\n/g' | sed '/^ *$/d' | sed 's/^ *//'
```

And output happened to be:

```
Sample page
html { color: #837456; }
body { background: white; }
Hello here!
```