# I want to remove html tags with sed, but my script does not work

Tags: shell, sed

I want to remove all the tags of html file, below is my code. My t

## Heading

hinking is: when encounters a `<` tag, then join all the lines, and do substitution. But the code does not work? Any ideas? Thanks a million.

```sh
sed '/</{
:loop
N
b loop
s/<[^<]*>//g
}
' index.html
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed remove tags from html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file)

Comment: Processing html, json or xml is not a job for `sed` or `awk`. There is no language validations built in. There can be tags with no closing tag like `</br>` and others. You need a html utility like `html2text`

Answer (score 0):

Guessing... Trying to get the big picture behind...

You need to convert HTML to text :)

So, what about a clean and proper way of doing this ?

```
html2text index.html
```

Check http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/