# Removing HTML Tags in Data pulled from SQL Database

Tags: html, sql, asp.net

I'm currently working on enhancing/redesigning a website of a client. The problem is the contents from their database is full of HTML tags because of how the website is built before. It is causing layout issues with the new design. How do I remove the HTML tags in the Data from the Database without manually editing the data in SQL since I'm not allowed to change anything from it?

[Here is a sample data pulled from the database. It has a div tag that needs to be removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BdVW.png)

What's happening is it adds another DIV in my layout:

```
<a href='Notices-Singular?rule={NoticeID}'>
    
        <h3>{NoticeTitle}</h3>
        <i>{NoticeDate}</i>
        <p><div align='justify'>Lorem Ipsum....</p><!-------Right here----->
    
</a>
```

BTW, I'm using Visual Studio ASP.NET for the website.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `sed` to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878056/sed-remove-tags-from-html-file - the answers also describe alternate methods.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 01:**
Can you make a function based on regular expression and then remove all the HTML tags in it?

```
static string RemoveHtmlTags(string input)
    {
        // Use a regular expression to match and remove HTML tags
        return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    }
```

Simply call this function and get plain text in return.

```
string plainText = RemoveHtmlTags(htmlText);
```

**OPTION 02**

Another option is that you identify all the tags in the text you are getting and put them in an array of string and then remove only these tags.

```
static string RemoveHtmlTags(string input)
    {
        string[] tagsToRemove = { "p", "b" };
        foreach (string tag in tagsToRemove)
        {
            string startTag = $"<{tag}>";
            string endTag = $"</{tag}>";

            // Remove the start tag and end tag, including their contents
            input = input.Replace(startTag, "").Replace(endTag, "");
        }

        return input;
    }
```